# python regular expression for retweets

Tags: python, regex, twitter

i'm working on a regex that will extract retweet keywords and user names from tweets. here's an example, with a rather terrible regex to do the job:

```
tweet='foobar RT@one, @two: @three barfoo'
m=re.search(r'(RT|retweet|from|via)\b\W*@(\w+)\b\W*@(\w+)\b\W*@(\w+)\b\W*',tweet)
m.groups()
('RT', 'one', 'two', 'three')
```

what i'd like is to condense the repeated `\b\W*@(\w+)\b\W*` patterns and make them of a variable number, so that if @four were added after @three, it would also be extracted. i've tried many permutations to repeat this with a `+` unsuccessfully.

i'd also like this to work for something like

```
tweet='foobar RT@one, RT @two: RT @three barfoo';
```

which can be achieved with a re.finditer *if* the patterns don't overlap. (i have a version where the patterns do overlap, and so only the first RT gets picked up.)

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I think this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558105/string-separation-in-required-format-pythonic-way-with-or-w-o-regex

Comment: Nm, it only partial answers because of the requirement here for RT/retweet, sorry.

Comment: thanks for passing this along -- although only a partial answer, definitely useful!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
(RT|retweet|from|via)(?:\b\W*@(\w+))+'
```

Enclosing the `\b\W*@(\w+)` in '(?:...)` allows you to group the terms for repetition without capturing the aggregate.

I'm not sure I'm following the second part of your question, but I think you may be looking for something involving a construct like:

```
(?:(?!RT|@).)
```

which will match any character that isn't an "@" or the start of "RT", again without capturing it.

In that case, how about:

```
(RT|retweet|from|via)((?:\b\W*@\w+)+)
```

and then post process

```
re.split(r'@(\w+)' ,m.groups()[1])
```

To get the individual handles?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!

unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, unless i've mistyped something:

    tweet='foobar RT@one, @two: @three barfoo'
    m=re.search(r'(RT|retweet|from|via)(?:\b\W*@(\w+))+',tweet)
    m.groups()
    ('RT', 'three')

but i will read up on (?:...). thanks.

Comment: thanks markus. i essentially ended up going with a method similar to this, but was bothered by not being able to come up with a one-regex solution. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A regex that can match most report/repost/modified post things is the following.

`\brt\b|#retweet|#modifiedpost|via @|\bmp\b|@\w*:|#rt|#mp|(rt|mt):? @\w*:?|`
Somthing like that should work to catch them.
Other relevant posts are
[Trying to find Twitter RT's with Regular Expressions and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461911/trying-to-find-twitter-rts-with-regular-expressions-and-php/1461949#1461949) and [How to strip off beginning of retweet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154068/how-to-strip-off-beginning-of-retweet)
Edit: added other responses