# How to strip off beginning of retweet?

Tags: php, regex

Whenever a Tweet is retweeted, the retweeting tweet usually has the same format:

```
RT @UserName: Original Tweet, sometimes with alterations
```

I'm looking for a way to split off the "RT @UserName:", so that only the original tweet remains. I think a regex checking the beginning of the tweet for "RT", and then check until the first space after @UserName should do the trick. I now have

```
preg_replace("/^RT/ui", "", $tweet);
```

but this only removes the RT. How can I expand this regex?

Second question: alternatively, it would probably also be possible to check for "RT" at the beginning of the tweet, and then only save the part of the string after the second space (first one is between RT and @UserName, so the first one after @UserName indicates the cut-off point), but then I would have a problem if for some reason there would be two spaces between RT and @UserName, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/^RT [^:]+:/ui", "", $tweet);
```

This will remove everything until the colon.

**EDIT:**

Apparently some retweets don't have a colon:

```
preg_replace("/^RT +@[^ :]+:? */ui", "", $tweet);
```

This will remove "RT", the username, an optional colon and also the  spaces before the message.

Comment: You may want to include the space after the first colon too.

Comment: `preg_replace("/^RT [^:]+: +/ui", "", $tweet);` will remove all the initial spaces after the first colon.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes there is no colon: "RT @UserName This is a tweet" so then this wouldn't work. That's why I think it would be best to look for the fist space after the username.

Comment: `preg_replace("/^RT +@[^ :]+:? */ui", "", $tweet);` :) If i'm correct, this should work in all the cases you mentioned.

Comment: @BrunoSilva: +1, but edit your answer instead of put in comment.

Comment: If the tweet was retweeted with the Retweet button on twitter, the status object should have a 'retweeted_status' property which is the original status object with the full (and non-RT @someone text).