# How do I make the introductory social network code from "Mining the Social Web" work?

Tags: python

I entered all the code from: https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web/blob/master/python_code/introduction__retweet_visualization.py

However, all I get is a "exit code 0" and no output whatsoever. How do I create the graph of retweets that is the goal of this code?

```
# =*= coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os 
import json
import re
import webbrowser
import codecs
import twitter
import networkx as nx

# Your query
Q = sys.argv[0]

# An HTLML page that we'll inject Protovis consumable data into
HTML_TEMPLATE =         '~/PyCharmProjects/twitter_movements/web_code/protovis/twitter_retweet_graph.html'
OUT = os.path.basename(HTML_TEMPLATE)
OUT_DIR = 'out'

# Writes out a dOT language file that can be converted into
# an image by Graphbiz
def write_dot_output(g, out_file):

    out_file += ".dot"

    if not os.path.isdir(OUT_DIR):
        os.mkdir(OUT_DIR)

    try:
        nx.drawing.write_dot(g, os.path.join(OUT_DIR, out_file))
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Data file written to: %s' % os.path. join(os.getcwd(), OUT_DIR, out_file)
    except (ImportError, UnicodeEncodeError):

        # The next block helps to fix a UnicodeEncodeError that occurs in write_dot.

        dot = ['"%s" -> "%s" [tweet_id+%s]' % (n1, n2, g[n1][n2]['tweet_id'])
               for (n1, n2) in g.edges()]
        f = codecs.open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), OUT_DIR, out_file), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        f.write('''strict digraph {
    %s
    }''' % (';\n'.join(dot), ))
        f.close()

        print >> sys.stderr, 'Data file written to: %s' % f.name

        return f.name

# Writes out an HTML page that can be opened in the browser
# that displays a graph
def write_protovis_output(g, out_file):
nodes = g.nodes()
indexed_nodes = {}

idx = 0
for n in nodes:
    indexed_nodes.update([(n, idx,)])
    idx += 1

links = []
for n1, n2 in g.edges():
    links.append({'source' : indexed_nodes[n2],
                  'target' : indexed_nodes[n1]})

    json_data = json.dumps({"nodes" : [{"nodeName" : n} for n in nodes], "links" : links}, indent=4)
    html = open(HTML_TEMPLATE).read() % (json_data,)
    if not os.path.isdir(OUT_DIR):
        os.mkdir(OUT_DIR)
    f = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), OUT_DIR, out_file + ".html"), 'w')
    f.write(html)
    f.close()

    print >> sys.stderr, 'Data file written to: %s' % f.name

    return f.name

# Given a tweet, pull out any retweet origins in it and return as a list
def get_rt_origins(tweet):
    # Regex adapted from
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655903/python-regular-expression-for-retweets
    rt_patterns = re.compile(r"(RT|via)((?:\b\W*@\w+)+)", re.IGNORECASE)
    rt_origins = []

    try:
        rt_origins += [mention.strip() for mention in rt_patterns.findall(tweet)[0][1].split()]
    except IndexError, e:
        pass

    return [rto.strip("@") for rto in rt_origins]

# Get some search results for a query
twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
search_results = []
for page in range(1,6):
    search_results.append(twitter_search.search(q=Q, rpp=100, page=page))

# Build up a graph data structure
    g = nx.DiGraph()

    all_tweets = [tweet for page in search_results for tweet in page['results']]
    for tweet in all_tweets:
        rt_origins = get_rt_origins(tweet['text'])
        if not rt_origins:
            continue
        for rt_origin in rt_origins:
            g.add_edge(rt_origin, tweet['from_user'], {'tweet_id': tweet['id']})

# Print out some stats
print >> sys.stderr, "Number nodes:", g.number_of_nodes()
print >> sys.stderr, "Num edges:", g.number_of_edges()
print >> sys.stderr, "Num connected components:", len(nx.connected_components(g.to_undirected()))
print >> sys.stderr, "Node degrees:", sorted(nx.degree(g))

# Write Graphviz output
write_dot_output(g, OUT)

# Write Protovis output and open in browser
protovis_output = write_protovis_output(g, OUT)
webbrowser.open('file://' + protovis_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sys.stdout instead of sys.stderr and you should see output properly

```
# Print out some stats
print >> sys.stdout, "Number nodes:", g.number_of_nodes()
print >> sys.stdout, "Num edges:", g.number_of_edges()
print >> sys.stdout, "Num connected components:", len(nx.connected_components(g.to_undirected()))
print >> sys.stdout, "Node degrees:", sorted(nx.degree(g))
```

Every where in this code you are trying to write to standard error rather than standard output.

Or run this program by redirecting stderr to stdout

```
python filename 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks pyfunc. However, it doesn't change the output whatsoever. Ideally I want the HTML, Graphviz, and Protovis output as specified in the comments. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Any additional insight into the original question?